# Dividing DataFrame's columns by column of the same DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I've got DataFrame read from csv:

```
Date             Name  NumOfUsers Value1 Value2 Value3
2018-07-23 09:00 AP1   12         12     24     2
2018-07-23 12:30 AP1   11         33     22     4
2018-07-23 14:05 AP2   43         86     86     8
2018-09-20 11:10 AP1   34         68     17     6
```

How can I sum all of the values for one Name from one day and divide it by NumOfUsers to receive this:

```
Date        Name  NumOfUsers Value1 Value2 Value3
2018-07-23  AP1   23         1.95   2      0.26
2018-07-23  AP2   43         2      2      0.18
2018-09-20  AP1   34         2      0.5    0.17
```

Now I use it:

```
df_new['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df_new['Date'])
df_new['just_date'] = df_new['Date'].dt.date
df_new.loc[:,"Value1":"Value3"] = df_new.loc[:,"Value1":"Value3"].div(df_new["Value1"], axis=0)
df_new.Value1.groupby([df_new.just_date, df_new.Name]).sum().reset_index().sort_values(by=["Value1"], ascending=False)
```

But in fields of values I receive only 0 or Inf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessaryaggregate `sum` by all columns and then division by column `NumOfUsers` by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df_new['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df_new['Date'])
df = df_new.groupby([df_new['Date'].dt.date, 'Name']).sum().reset_index()
df.loc[:,"Value1":"Value3"] = df.loc[:,"Value1":"Value3"].div(df["NumOfUsers"], axis=0)
print (df)
         Date Name  NumOfUsers    Value1  Value2    Value3
0  2018-07-23  AP1          23  1.956522     2.0  0.260870
1  2018-07-23  AP2          43  2.000000     2.0  0.186047
2  2018-09-20  AP1          34  2.000000     0.5  0.176471
```